# Windows 7 Ultimate, death blue screen with new kingston memory

Tags: windows-7, memory, ddr2

My system operations (Windows 7 Ultimate), was working perfectly with 1x2G (RAM DDR2) by months, but I bought new 4GB (2x2GB RAM DDR2) by kingston.

Retired my old memory 2gb and install the new 2x2gb on slot 3 and 4 of my motherboard (ECS A780GM-A).

The user manual of motherboard speak about the best performance of memory should installed on slot 3 and 4.

The problem: After 2 hours use more or less. My system crash (death blue screen). Before the new memory, it never happened.

Can anybody help me?

See below my blue screen dump

Created by using BlueScreenView

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 021212-21325-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12/02/2012 11:38:18
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 0xc0119fa8
Parameter 2       : 0x00000000
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x82ac26e1
Caused By Driver  : halmacpi.dll
Caused By Address : halmacpi.dll+5ba9
File Description  : Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+4686b
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+726e1
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7373b
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+73400
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\021212-21325-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 144.016
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 021112-20482-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11/02/2012 18:48:15
Bug Check String  : KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000008e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x89144885
Parameter 3       : 0x9d1efa60
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : fltmgr.sys
Caused By Address : fltmgr.sys+a885
File Description  : Gerenciador de Filtro do Filesystem Microsoft
Product Name      : Sistema Operacional Microsoft® Windows®
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : fltmgr.sys+a885
Stack Address 1   : fltmgr.sys+a8ed
Stack Address 2   : fltmgr.sys+3340
Stack Address 3   : fltmgr.sys+3455
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\021112-20482-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 144.016
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 020912-21668-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 09/02/2012 14:17:18
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 0x00005002
Parameter 2       : 0xc0802000
Parameter 3       : 0x000002ec
Parameter 4       : 0x102edffe
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+dce34
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16905 (win7_gdr.111025-1503)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+dce34
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+99b79
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8eddf
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+876e0
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\020912-21668-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 144.016
==================================================
```

See below my report system by everest.

```
--------[ EVEREST Ultimate Edition ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Operating System                                  Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1.7600
    Date                                              2012-02-12
    Time                                              12:39


--------[ Summary ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Computer:
      Computer Type                                     PC baseado em ACPI x86
      Operating System                                  Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
      OS Service Pack                                   -
      Internet Explorer                                 9.0.8112.16421
      DirectX                                           DirectX 10.1
      Date / Time                                       2012-02-12 / 12:39

    Motherboard:
      CPU Type                                          QuadCore AMD Athlon X4 620, 2600 MHz (13 x 200)
      Motherboard Name                                  ECS A780GM-A  (3 PCI, 2 PCI-E x1, 1 PCI-E x16, 4 DDR2 DIMM, Audio, Video, Gigabit LAN)
      Motherboard Chipset                               AMD 780G, AMD K10
      System Memory                                     2304 MB  (DDR2-800 DDR2 SDRAM)
      DIMM3:                                            2 GB DDR2-800 DDR2 SDRAM  (6-6-6-18 @ 400 MHz)  (5-5-5-15 @ 333 MHz)  (4-4-4-12 @ 266 MHz)
      DIMM4: Kingston                                   2 GB DDR2-800 DDR2 SDRAM  (5-5-5-18 @ 400 MHz)  (4-4-4-12 @ 266 MHz)  (3-3-3-9 @ 200 MHz)
      BIOS Type                                         AMI (11/23/09)
      Communication Port                                Porta de comunicação (COM1)

    Display:
      Video Adapter                                     ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics (Microsoft Corporation WDDM 1.1)  (1024 MB)
      Video Adapter                                     ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics (Microsoft Corporation WDDM 1.1)  (1024 MB)
      3D Accelerator                                    ATI Radeon HD 3200 (RS780)
      Monitor                                           Samsung SyncMaster 906BW/931BW/931CW/MagicSyncMaster CX931BW (Analog)  [19" LCD]  (HXGP502381)

    Multimedia:
      Audio Adapter                                     ATI RS690 HDMI @ AMD RS780(M) Chipset - High Definition Audio Controller
      Audio Adapter                                     ATI RS690 HDMI @ ATI SB700 - High Definition Audio Controller

    Storage:
      IDE Controller                                    Controlador de canal duplo padrão PCI IDE
      IDE Controller                                    Controlador de canal duplo padrão PCI IDE
      Disk Drive                                        MAXTOR STM3250310AS ATA Device  (250 GB, 7200 RPM, SATA-II)
      Disk Drive                                        SONY "PSP" MS USB Device  (7 GB, USB)
      Optical Drive                                     HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-4163B ATA Device  (DVD+R9:4x, DVD+RW:16x/8x, DVD-RW:16x/6x, DVD-RAM:5x, DVD-ROM:16x, CD:40x/24x/40x DVD+RW/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM)
      Optical Drive                                     MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ240AS USB Device
      SMART Hard Disks Status                           OK

    Partitions:
      C: (NTFS)                                         232.8 GB (90.1 GB free)
      Total Size                                        232.8 GB (90.1 GB free)

    Input:
      Keyboard                                          Dispositivo de teclado HID
      Mouse                                             Mouse compatível com HID

    Network:
      Primary IP Address                                192.168.10.10
      Primary MAC Address                               44-87-FC-55-10-57
      Network Adapter                                   NIC Gigabit Ethernet PCI-E Realtek Família RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) (NDIS 6.20)  (192.168.10.10)
      Network Adapter                                   Ralink RT61 Turbo Wireless LAN Card
      Network Adapter                                   TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS


--------[ DMI ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [ BIOS ]

    BIOS Properties:
      Vendor                                            American Megatrends Inc.
      Version                                           080014
      Release Date                                      11/23/2009
      Size                                              1024 KB
      Boot Devices                                      Floppy Disk, Hard Disk, CD-ROM, ATAPI ZIP, LS-120
      Capabilities                                      Flash BIOS, Shadow BIOS, Selectable Boot, EDD, BBS
      Supported Standards                               DMI, APM, ACPI, ESCD, PnP
      Expansion Capabilities                            ISA, PCI, USB

  [ System ]

    System Properties:
      Manufacturer                                      ECS
      Product                                           A780GM-A
      Version                                           1.0
      Universal Unique ID                               00020003-00040005-00060007-00080009
      Wake-Up Type                                      Power Switch

  [ Motherboard ]

    Motherboard Properties:
      Manufacturer                                      ECS
      Product                                           A780GM-A
      Version                                           1.0

  [ Chassis ]

    Chassis Properties:
      Manufacturer                                      ECS
      Chassis Type                                      Desktop Case
      Boot-Up State                                     Safe
      Power Supply State                                Safe
      Thermal State                                     Safe
      Security Status                                   None

  [ Processors / AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620 Processor ]

    Processor Properties:
      Manufacturer                                      AMD
      Version                                           AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620 Processor
      Serial Number                                     To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      Asset Tag                                         To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      Part Number                                       To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      External Clock                                    200 MHz
      Maximum Clock                                     2600 MHz
      Current Clock                                     2600 MHz
      Type                                              Central Processor
      Voltage                                           1.5 V
      Status                                            Enabled
      Socket Designation                                CPU 1
      HTT / CMP Units                                   0 / 4

  [ Caches / L1-Cache ]

    Cache Properties:
      Type                                              Internal
      Status                                            Enabled
      Operational Mode                                  Varies with Memory Address
      Associativity                                     4-way Set-Associative
      Maximum Size                                      512 KB
      Installed Size                                    512 KB
      Supported SRAM Type                               Pipeline Burst
      Current SRAM Type                                 Pipeline Burst
      Error Correction                                  Single-bit ECC
      Socket Designation                                L1-Cache

  [ Caches / L2-Cache ]

    Cache Properties:
      Type                                              Internal
      Status                                            Enabled
      Operational Mode                                  Varies with Memory Address
      Associativity                                     4-way Set-Associative
      Maximum Size                                      2048 KB
      Installed Size                                    2048 KB
      Supported SRAM Type                               Pipeline Burst
      Current SRAM Type                                 Pipeline Burst
      Error Correction                                  Single-bit ECC
      Socket Designation                                L2-Cache

  [ Caches / L3-Cache ]

    Cache Properties:
      Type                                              Internal
      Status                                            Disabled
      Maximum Size                                      0 KB
      Installed Size                                    0 KB
      Socket Designation                                L3-Cache

  [ Memory Devices / DIMM0 ]

    Memory Device Properties:
      Form Factor                                       DIMM
      Type                                              DDR2
      Type Detail                                       Synchronous
      Speed                                             333 MHz
      Total Width                                       64-bit
      Data Width                                        72-bit
      Device Locator                                    DIMM0
      Bank Locator                                      BANK0
      Manufacturer                                      Manufacturer0
      Serial Number                                     SerNum0
      Asset Tag                                         AssetTagNum0
      Part Number                                       PartNum0

  [ Memory Devices / DIMM1 ]

    Memory Device Properties:
      Form Factor                                       DIMM
      Type                                              DDR2
      Type Detail                                       Synchronous
      Speed                                             333 MHz
      Total Width                                       64-bit
      Data Width                                        72-bit
      Device Locator                                    DIMM1
      Bank Locator                                      BANK1
      Manufacturer                                      Manufacturer1
      Serial Number                                     SerNum1
      Asset Tag                                         AssetTagNum1
      Part Number                                       PartNum1

  [ Memory Devices / DIMM2 ]

    Memory Device Properties:
      Form Factor                                       DIMM
      Type                                              DDR2
      Type Detail                                       Synchronous
      Size                                              2048 MB
      Speed                                             333 MHz
      Total Width                                       64-bit
      Data Width                                        72-bit
      Device Locator                                    DIMM2
      Bank Locator                                      BANK2
      Manufacturer                                      Manufacturer2
      Serial Number                                     SerNum2
      Asset Tag                                         AssetTagNum2
      Part Number                                       PartNum2

  [ Memory Devices / DIMM3 ]

    Memory Device Properties:
      Form Factor                                       DIMM
      Type                                              DDR2
      Type Detail                                       Synchronous
      Size                                              2048 MB
      Speed                                             333 MHz
      Total Width                                       64-bit
      Data Width                                        72-bit
      Device Locator                                    DIMM3
      Bank Locator                                      BANK3
      Manufacturer                                      Manufacturer3
      Serial Number                                     SerNum3
      Asset Tag                                         AssetTagNum3
      Part Number                                       PartNum3
```

Comment: Run memtest overnight.

Answer (score 0):

With the first crash on th 9th clearly happening from a memory error, and the other two unhandled exceptions in drivers - and based on this happening with the addition of the memory, it seems strong that one (or both) of the two new memory sticks is bad. Your bios should have a boot time option to do extended memory diagnostics. Let that run over night. If it generates any error logs, request a replacement from the manufactor.